# AonDor vs other Dor methods?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

On Sel, one of the ways you can access the Dor is becoming an Elantarian. There are two prerequisites to this:

1. The person must be of Aonic descent, and
2. they must be "chosen" by the Shaod.

However, there are other ways to access the Dor: Dakhor, ChayShan, as well as Forgery and Bloodsealing. These methods – unlike AonDor – anyone can become one of these, provided that they are from the correct descent. Why is there no additional random prerequisite like the Shaod?

Comment: Each of them are tied to their land - the "base" Aon (rune? am I screwing that up) always being a pictogram of the land in question.  Likely part of the working is also a connection to that land, although because of being descended there, or because of the knowledge and Aon, unknown.  We haven't been given enough info to know why each of them works the way it does... or if just the fact that Elantris was created means it changed the way the Dor works there.

Comment: the Shaod may be an effect of the city of Elantris and it's boosting effects